# Chaining promises to display custom JS alert boxes one after the other

Tags: javascript, html, es6-promise, alert

EDIT: Thanks to Nick Parson's response below, I realized I should be returning a new promise inside showAlert() every time it's called. This works:

```
const showAlert = (headerText, bodyText) => {
    console.log(headerText);
    let modalHeaderText = document.getElementById("modal-header-text"); 
    let modalBodyText = document.getElementById("modal-body-text"); 
    modalHeaderText.textContent = headerText;
    modalBodyText.textContent = bodyText;
    modal.style.display = "block";

    return new Promise(function(myResolve) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    
        let modalButton = document.getElementById("continue-button");
            modalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                modal.style.display = "none";
                myResolve("OK");
            })
      });

}
```

---

I'm building a game with vanilla JS/HTML/CSS and am trying to build a custom alert box to replicate the functionality of Javascript `alert()` while adding custom styling. There are several situations in my game where multiple alert boxes will need to be shown one after the other, but only when the user clicks on the "Continue" button in the box. From what I understand, the only way to do this is to use Promises that resolve on the "Continue" button clicks – however, I'm having some unexpected issues with my implementation.

Here's the code that is responsible for showing the alert boxes i.e. modals (and setting the header + body of them) and handling button clicks:

```
// promise that waits for button click
let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    let modalButton = document.getElementById("continue-button");
        modalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            myResolve("OK");
        })
});
 


// function that shows the alert and sets content
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

const showAlert = (headerText, bodyText) => {
    console.log(headerText);
    let modalHeaderText = document.getElementById("modal-header-text"); 
    let modalBodyText = document.getElementById("modal-body-text"); 
    modalHeaderText.textContent = headerText;
    modalBodyText.textContent = bodyText;
    modal.style.display = "block";

    return myPromise;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
showAlert("first header", "1").then(() => showAlert("second header", "2")).then(() => (showAlert("third header", "3")));
```

However, when I run my code, it shows me the first alert and then on clicking continue, skips to the third alert. Through console logging I see that the second `showAlert()` is also called but for some reason doesn't wait for the promise to resolve i.e. the button to be clicked. I've tried rearranging the way `.then` is chained but it always shows the first and last alert boxes, skipping the ones in the middle. Any pointers on what I'm missing or how I could achieve this goal better would be incredibly useful!

Comment: A Promise can only be resolved once. In your code, you only create one promise which you resolve when you click continue on your first alert. Try making the Promise inside of `showAlert()`

Comment: Ahhh that makes a ton of sense - it works now! Thank you so much :)